# Blender to Unity Deform Issue

Tags: unity

I received a rigged model from someone I hired but there's issues with the legs/feet in Unity that they're not fixing. There's no issue in Blender, just Unity. I don't know Blender at all but I'm trying to fix this issue where the feet are deforming when the leg is rotated. Here's a short video of the issue.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1QGjhPE3-TU3ruQyCXN6A2Fk4_ddge8lF/view?usp=sharing

I've tried reexporting the blender file with optimal FBX settings and changed the animations compression to optimal and rotation/position error to 0 but still no go.

Would anyone be able to help with this? I'm willing to pay a bit to get it fixed.

Comment: While files, images, and external links may be helpful additions to questions they should not be the only way to obtain information about your issue. Don't make understanding your question rely on downloading a file or visiting an external site. Use the builtin tools to upload [images](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) or [gifs](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963), along with thoroughly explaining the problem in written form so it can be searched for and indexed thus helping future users with similar issues find it.

Comment: What? How can I be more specific? I've included a video with the exact issue and explained the issue. Give me a break.

Comment: This problem is usually occurs, when the area is affected by two or more bones unnecessarily.